# Disassembling pre-assembled JST Rectangular Plug PHR-4 (0.079")

Tags: connector, header, terminal

I'm going to purchase pre-assembled 4-Position Cable Assembly [CABLE-PH04](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/trinamic-motion-control-gmbh/CABLE-PH04/1460-1295-ND/9381900) with standard PHR-4 JST connector housing [0.079" (2.00mm) pitch].
The PHR-4 JST connector plug will be connected to mating 4-pos male Connector [Header](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?mpart=B4B-PH-K-S%28LF%29%28SN%29&v=455) on PCB. For my needs, I need 3 wires connected on PHR-4 plug, so one wire is superfluous, and I need to remove it.
My question is, does it possible accurately pull out the single wire from JST PHR-4 plug without damaging the slight connector housing? If yes, how to pull out the wire accurately?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Once you get the hang of it, it is very easy. Terminology: the plastic part is called a housing. The female pin in the plug is called a pin or crimp fitting. The crimp fitting stays in the housing because a raised area is unable to slip past a plastic tab in the housing. To remove, slip an exacto knife blade under the plastic tab on the outside of the housing while simultaneously pulling the un-needed wire out of the plastic housing. Do not pull forcefully. Once the raised metal piece passes the plastic tab, the wire with crimp fitting on end should pull out easily.

Comment: I pulled out only wires, the metal pins remained stay inside the housing. I managed to pull out wires with crimp fitting from 2.5mm pitch JST housing, but have no success with 2.0mm housing, too small.